# StrSplit in Pig functions

Tags: apache-pig

Can Some one explain me on getting this below output in Pigscript

my input file is below

a.txt

```
aaa.kyl,data,data
bbb.kkk,data,data
cccccc.hj,data,data
qa.dff,data,data
```

I am writing the pig script like this

```
A = LOAD 'a.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(a1:chararray,a2:chararray,a3:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(a1)),a2,a3;
```

I dont know how to proceed with this..
i need out put like this below.Basically  i need all chars after the dot symbol in the first atom

```
(kyl,data,data)
(kkk,data,data)
(hj,data,data)
(dff,data,data)
```

Can some one give me the code for this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is what you need to do -

Here is an escaping problem in the pig parsing routines when it encounters the dot as its considered as an operator refer this link for more information [Dot Operator](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html).

You can use a unicode escape sequence for a dot instead: \u002E. However this must also be slash escaped and put in a single quoted string.

The below code will do the work for you and you can fine tune it as per your convenience -

```
A = LOAD 'a.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(a1:chararray,a2:chararray,a3:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(a1,'\\u002E')) as (a1:chararray, a1of1:chararray),a2,a3;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE a1of1,a2,a3;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice explanation.. Do we  need to apply this kind of unicode escape sequence for pipe symbol and comma as well.

Comment: No not for pipe and comma check the pig documentation

Answer (score 4):

You can try with STRSPLIT() by following,

```
A = LOAD 'C:\\Users\\Ren\\Desktop\\file' USING PigStorage(',') AS(a1:chararray,a2:chararray,a3:chararray); 

B = foreach A generate SUBSTRING(a1,INDEXOF(a1,'.',0)+1,(int)SIZE(a1)),a2,a3;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A = LOAD 'a.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(a1:chararray,a2:chararray,a3:chararray);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(a1,'.')),a2,a3;
```

This will seperate a1 into 2 parts which is before dot and after dot, from this you can select after dot operator.

```
C = foreach B generate $1,$2,$3;
```

where **$1** is after Dot operator